# Why b[:]=a mutates list b?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

Suppose we have a list `a=[1,2,3]` and I need to copy elements of `a` to new list `b`.

we can do `a=b` but both `a` and `b` point to the same list. Hence mutating either of them mutates both the lists.

```
>>> a=b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
>>> b.append(4)
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.append(5)
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a is b
True
>>> id(a),id(b)
(2287659980360, 2287659980360)
```

To avoid this we can do `b=a[:]`. `a[:]` creates a different list with the same values of `a`. Now, even if I mutate `a`, `b` will not be affected and vice-versa. `b` and `b[:]` are two different lists.

```
>>> b=a[:]
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.append(6)
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> b.append(6)
>>> a,b
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a is b
False
>>> id(a),id(b)
(2287659980360, 2287653308552)
```

Now, if I do `b[:]=a` my list `b` is being mutated. But `b[:]` is another list right? Both `b` and `b[:]` point to different lists right? Correct me if I'm wrong. Why is `b` being changed if I mutate `b[:]`. What am I missing?

```
>>> a=['a','b','c']
>>> b[:]=a
>>> a,b
(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> id(b),id(b[:])
(2287653308552, 2287660267080)
>>> b is b[:]
False
```

Comment: `"Now, if I do b[:]=a my list b is being mutated."` not exactly mutated, rather overwritten by another list, which is renamed as `b`.

Comment: Not an expert, but I assume that when `b[:]` is assigned to, it modifies the list `b`. However, when `b[:]` is called on the right hand side, it returns a list containing every element of `b`, which points to a different location#

Comment: @SayandipDutta absolutely not. The list being referred to by `b` is being mutated.

Comment: You are confusing two things, slicing and slice-based assignment. The expression `x[:]` creates a slice, implicitly calling `x.__getitem__`, whereas the statement `x[:] = b` is slice assignment, which calls `x.__setitem__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for taking out your time in explaining and finding a similar question.Now I understood the difference.

Comment: Please keep Q&A style posts as they are, do not post answers in the question post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slicing means different things when used as an expression or as an assignment target.

As an expression, evaluating `b[:]` produces a new list. However, as an assignment target, assigning to `b[:]` does not mean "evaluate the expression `b[:]` and then assign to the resulting list". You can't assign to objects in Python, anyway.

As an assignment target, assigning to `b[:]` tells the existing list to replace its contents with the elements of whatever you're assigning to `b[:]`. This is handled by the `__setitem__` method, like `b.__setitem__(slice(None, None), a)`. No new list is produced, and `b[:]` is not evaluated as an expression.

You can see this described in the [language reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for assignment statements, under "If the target is a slicing" (although some of the constraints for slice assignment aren't as strict as what the documentation describes; for example, the docs say the sequence types need to match, but for most types, they don't).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. Pretty clear explanation.

Comment: What did you mean by `You can't assign to objects in Python, anyway`

Comment: @Willwsharp: Assignment assigns to things like variables or attributes in Python, not objects. This is in contrast to languages like C++.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Hmm what does that look like in C++?  I think I'm drawing a blank on this.  Thanks!

Comment: @Willwsharp: In Python, if you do `a.b = c`, then `a` is responsible for rebinding its `b` attribute. In C++, if you do `a.b = c;`, then the `a.b` object is responsible for modifying itself to look like `c`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Oh I think I understand. What should I search to learn more about this?